# Filter dictionary array with multiple value

Tags: objective-c

```
(
        {
        iReplyId = 3870;
        name = rahul;
    },
        {
        iReplyId = 3914;
        name = Tom;
    },
        {
        iReplyId = 3873;
        name = Smith;
    },
        {
        iReplyId = 3871;
        name = yator;
    },
        {
        iReplyId = 3872;
        name = jack;
    },
        {
        iReplyId = 3875;
        name = smith;
    },
        {
        iReplyId = 3876;
        name = rancho;
    },

        {
        iReplyId = 3878;
        name = vid;
    },

)
```

My requirement is to filter this array with multiple condtion like iReplyId = 3871,3870,3914 by using nspredicate. i tried so much but but i didn't get the solution with predicate, i can solve this by using for loop but that is not a good way.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: How you want your final data to be ?

Answer (score 0):

```
[array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"iReplyId IN (%@)",[idsArray componentsJoinedByString:@","]]]
```